# Finding the file with pattern including dot and varying string after dot

Tags: python, regex, file-handling

I want to search for the files `VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1.[some varying number].*` in the sub-folders of HGG_LGG.For example search for `VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1.25987.mha`in sub-folders of HGG_LGG.I could have use simply `VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1.*` for doing that but problem is there are files like `VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1c.[some varying number] .*`which I do not want to scan. In short I want entire string(**including dot(.)**) after T1 and then apply wildcard `.*` on that string. Following is the code. I tried to use `\\` for escaping the dot but did not work `matches` is still empty.

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/ms/Desktop/Testing/HGG_LGG/'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1\\..*'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: Try with re module. `for filename in [f for f in filenames if re.match(r'VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1\\..*', filenames)]`

Comment: filenames is a list.So using re.match throws type error.

Comment: Check now. I meant. `re.match(r'VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1\..*', f)`. `fnmatch()` won't do the regex match, it has limited wildcard usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit tricky. In order to find all the files of the form `VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1c.[some varying number] .*` so the penultimate dot is included then some varying string and then all extensions in which file was saved we need to use regex as pointed in the comments.

Using directly VSD.Br.XX.O.MR_T1.* did fetch other files. Here is the screenshot showing the same.

[image]

Following solution worked for me.

```
import os
import re

matches = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/ms/Desktop/Testing/HGG_LGG/'):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if re.match('VSD.Brain.XX.O.MR_T1\\..*', f)]:
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Thanks [MYGz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082217/mygz) for pointing out in the comment